# Kafka10 heartbeat.interval.ms property

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I am confused with the property heartbeat.interval.ms and poll() method.

I hope, poll() method will send the heartbeat when we invoke the poll() method. Say, heartbeat.interval.ms is configured to 1 sec, but the poll() method takes 2 secs to complete the processing. Will it send heartbeat after 2 secs or every one second thru the background thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I see `heartbeat.interval.ms` as the lower bound for heartbeat interval. That's to say, if you set it to 1 second, heartbeat thread must wait for at least 1 second to send the heartbeat request, but it's possible for the thread to wait up 1.5 seconds before sending request.

As of 0.10.1, heartbeating is moved from the user thread which calls `poll` to a separate thread, so it has no interleaving with `poll` things anymore. See further information in details: [KIP-62](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-62%3A+Allow+consumer+to+send+heartbeats+from+a+background+thread)

Comment: Do we have heartbeat.interval.ms in 0.10.1? I see 2 other props also. session.timeout.ms, max.poll.interval.ms. Confused with these 3.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991845/kafka10-1-heartbeat-interval-ms-session-timeout-ms-and-max-poll-interval-ms/43992308?noredirect=1#comment75014108_43992308 which is also posted by you.