# parallel stream with kafka consumer records

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have kafka records:

```
ConsumerRecords<String, Events> records = kafkaConsumer.poll(POLL_TIMEOUT);
```

I want to run the below code using parallel streams, not multithreading.

```
                records.forEach((record) -> {
                Event event = record.value();

                       HTTPSend.send(event);

            });
```

I tried with mlutithreading but I want to try parallelstream:

```
for (ConsumerRecord<String, Event> record : records) {
                        executor.execute(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {

                                        HTTPSend.send(Event);

                            }
                        });

                    }
```

Actually I'm facing issue with HTTP.send with multithreading (even with a thread pool of 1 thread). I'm getting

`"Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target"`. 
This is a request over https. This error comes only for the first time the request is made. Afterwards, the exception vanishes. poof!

For multithreading i'm using:

```
int threadCOunt=1;
                BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(threadCOunt, true);
                RejectedExecutionHandler handler = new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy();
                ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadCOunt, threadCOunt, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue, handler);
```

HTTPSend.send() is:

```
long sizeSend = 0;
    SSLContext sc = null;

    try {
        sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        sc.init(null, TRUST_ALL_CERTS, new SecureRandom());
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | KeyManagementException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Failed to create SSL context", e);
    }

    // Ignore differences between given hostname and certificate hostname
    HostnameVerifier hv = (hostname, session) -> true;

    // Create the REST client and configure it to connect meta
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .hostnameVerifier(hv)
            .sslContext(sc).build();

    WebTarget baseTarget = client.target(getURL()).path(HTTP_PATH);
    Response jsonResponse = null;

    try {
        StringBuilder eventsBatchString = new StringBuilder();
        eventsBatchString.append(this.getEvent(event));
        Entity<String> entity = Entity.entity(eventsBatchString.toString(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        builder = baseTarget.request();
        LOGGER.debug("about to send the event {} and URL {}", entity, getURL());
        jsonResponse = builder.header(HTTP_ACK_CHANNEL, guid.toString())
                .header("Content-type", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .header("Authorization", String.format("Meta %s", eventsModuleConfig.getSecretKey()))
                .post(entity);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see what you want to do, and I'm not sure that's the best idea (I'm also not sure it's *not*).

The `poll` / `commit` model of Kafka allows simple backpressure and retention of the last item processed if you crashed. By returning to your poll loop "immediately" you are telling Kafka "I am ready for more", and committing the offset (manually or automatically) tells Kafka that you have successfully read up to that point.

What you seem to want to do is read off Kafka as fast as possible, committing offsets, then putting the Kafka records into an executor queue then you balance your requests per second etc from that.

I'm not 100% sure that's a good idea: what happens if your app crashes? You may have committed some Kafka messages that actually didn't make it upstream. If you do really want to do this, I would suggest manually committing the offset (via `commitSync`) upon completion of the `Runnable`, instead of letting the high level consumer do it for you.

Why might you want to use a thread executor: I think these can be accomplished with Kafka too.

You may want to post multiple messages to the web server at the same time. A well paritioned Kafka topic will let multiple consumers / consumer groups consumer multiple partitions, thus - assuming a perfectly scaling HTTP server - would let you parallelize the posting of messages to your server. Yay for process based concurrency!

Maybe the web server is not perfectly scalable, or slow for this request (say each request takes 1 second): you need to limit the number of requests per second the web server takes, if you have a queue you might have a couple threads posting while not backing up Kafka.

In this case you can set [max.poll.records](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-41%3A+KafkaConsumer+Max+Records) to a scalable value that your web server requires. There's probably a better way to do this too, although it's escaping me at the moment.

If your web server takes a long time to respond you may get errors related to failing heartbeats. In that case I direct you to [this SO answer on the timeout / heartbeat topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43992308/224334).

Instead of using a thread executioner, thus making synchronous HTTP requests appear to be async, I would use an evented HTTP client like [Netty](https://netty.io/), thus achieving parallelism without thread based concurrency.

Comment: Actually I'm facing issue with HTTP.send with multithreading (even with a thread pool of 1 thread). I'm getting

"Caused by: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target". 

this is a request over https. This error comes only for the first time the request is made. Afterwards, the exception vanishes. poof!

Comment: Using blocking queue and ... 
int threadCOunt=1;
                    BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<Runnable>(threadCOunt, true);
                    RejectedExecutionHandler handler = new ThreadPoolExecutor.CallerRunsPolicy();
                    ExecutorService executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(threadCOunt, threadCOunt, 0L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, queue, handler);

Comment: My bet is that you can extract your post out of your Kafka program and it will give the same error. I would try to debug the issue by seperating the two things: "it throws an error connecting to the server!?' and 'how do I make Kafka do what I (think I) want?'

Comment: I made the edits to the question. Multithreading in kafka was done to increase performance but then i started getting the PKIX exception

Answer (score 0):

For solving a "slow consumer" use case where you're doing I/O processing, you should use something like [Parallel Consumer](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (PC) to avoid the "[head of line blocking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Head-of-line_blocking)" problem you're describing.

By using PC, you can processing all your keys in parallel, regardless of how long it takes to do your I/O.

It also comes with a non blocking Vert.x module which more efficiently uses the CPU.

PC directly solves for this, by sub partitioning the input partitions by key and processing each key in parallel.
It also tracks per record acknowledgement. Check out [Parallel Consumer on GitHub](https://github.com/confluentinc/parallel-consumer) (it's open source BTW, and I'm the author).