# Auto offset commit failed for group my_group_id in kafka confluent cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-python

I have a **Confluent Kafka** Cluster with 3 nodes and I using [kafka-python](http://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/index.html) for connect to `Kafka` and consume.

my `index.py`file :

```
cid = "_" + str(randint(1, 99999999))

consumer = KafkaConsumer('test', bootstrap_servers=['109.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092', '5.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092', '88.XXX.XXX.XXX:9092'], group_id='my_group_id', client_id=cid, auto_offset_reset='earliest')
for msg in consumer:
    logger.warning(msg.value)
```

I run the `index.py` file three times so I have Consumer Group with 3 Consumers and every consumer receives the messages in a partition and everything is fine.

When the messages in the `Topic` are finished, **2** The Consumer encounter this warning, and only one Consumer is connected to the Topic.

**warning** message :

```
[2018-07-10 12:32:38] (kafka.coordinator.consumer) WARNING : Auto offset commit failed for group my_group_id: CommitFailedError: Commit cannot be completed since the group has already
        rebalanced and assigned the partitions to another member.
        This means that the time between subsequent calls to poll()
        was longer than the configured max_poll_interval_ms, which
        typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much
        time message processing. You can address this either by
        increasing the rebalance timeout with max_poll_interval_ms,
        or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll()
        with max_poll_records.
```

Why does this message appear?
I changed `max_poll_interval_ms‍` but the problem did not resolve.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43991845/kafka10-1-heartbeat-interval-ms-session-timeout-ms-and-max-poll-interval-ms#43992308) answer might be relevant for you.

Comment: Have you found solution for this issue?